# Greensock gsap javascript throwing error and demo in codepen

Tags: javascript, function, syntax-error, gsap

I have been working on an animation using javascript, but I'm getting an error that I cannot seem to solve.

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/yayaCreates/pen/rNOOqWy?editors=1111)

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' 
 at https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/index.html?editors=1111&key=iFrameKey-4c841d24-2860-062c-bd95-881b1c346876:-5
```

But I do not see where it is missing a '.' anywhere. I have tried using SublimeText Linter as well. Any ideas?

Comment: I have also tried removing functions to find the culprit. No success. I wonder if my syntax at the end of the javascript needs a final punctuation mark. Nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove all ***;*** before ***.to*** and ***.fromTo***

Then this error is fixed.

Comment: Hello Vladimir, I will try that right now. Thank you!